# How do I find out what is being executed when DOMContentLoaded is fired in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, document-ready, domcontentloaded

Is there a way to get all of the code that will be executed when DOMContentLoaded is fired, or jQuery's $(document).ready() function.

I am trying to optimize my site and through a speed test, I found that 2 seconds of the page's load time is spent handling the events when DOMContentLoaded is fired.

Comment: can you just do a text search for all `.ready()` functions and look ?

Answer (score 2):

I would highly recommend the Chrome profiler for this task:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OxW1dCjOstE

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
console.log($(document).data("events").ready);
```

Based on John Resig's post here: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/list-event-listeners

Also, check out the [`listHandlers` plugin.](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/debug-jquery-events-with-listhandlers/)

If all else fails, you could temporarily edit the core jQuery file:

```
ready: function( fn ) {    
    //create a wrapper function so we can step into the debugger
    var fn2 = function() {
        var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
        debugger; // <-- start debugging each handler as it fires
        return fn.apply(this, args);
    }

    // Attach the listeners
    jQuery.bindReady();

    // Add the callback
    readyList.add( fn2 );

    return this;    
},
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Network Panel info in the Chrome Developer Tools documentation](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/network),`DomContentLoaded`has fired off once the blue line appears. FWIW, `load` has fired off once the red line appears.